# What is the symmetry group of this Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

Consider a Hamiltonian

$$\hat H=-\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2+(x-y)Q,$$

where $x,y\in[0,a]$ (homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions assumed), and $Q$ is some real parameter.

When $Q=0$, the Hamiltonian describes a 2D particle in a box, and the symmetry group is [dihedral group of order 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_groups#The_symmetry_group_of_a_square_-_dihedral_group_of_order_8), which has two complex conjugate irreducible representations, giving rise to a two-fold degeneracy of spectrum.

But choosing $Q\ne0$ should lift this degeneracy, because, as it seems, the symmetry reduces to [cyclic group of order 2](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_group:Z2). But when I solve Schrödinger's equation with this setting, the degeneracy doesn't appear to be lifted, no matter how large $Q$ I take! So, I must be missing some other symmetry operations than just reflection with respect to $x=a-y$ line.

So, what are these extra symmetry operations? Or is the extra symmetry here something hidden like dynamical symmetry of Coulomb potential?

What's interesting, the degeneracy is lifted when I take $(x-y)^\alpha$ instead of $(x-y)$, where $\alpha\ne1$. Also what's common between the cases of $Q=0$ and $Q\ne0$ is that Schrödinger's equation is separable, unlike the case of $\alpha\ne1$.

Actually, $\hat H$ is a sum of two Hamiltonians acting on independent degrees of freedom and having identical spectra. This somewhat gives intuitive expectation that the spectrum must be degenerate: there do exist states like $\left|a\right\rangle\otimes\left|b\right\rangle$ as well as $\left|b\right\rangle\otimes\left|a\right\rangle$ (with appropriate modifications), which must have equal energies, but still: **what symmetry group results** to explain the degeneracy from symmetry POV?

Comment: Did you try to pass to coordinates $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$? I am not sure but perhaps it is easier.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I did think of this, but don't forget about the boundaries — they still are at finite points and break possible translational symmetry with respect to $v$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you asking about the reflection symmetry about the line $y=a-x$? You hamiltonian with the potential has that symmetry, so you will get degeneracies.

Comment: Is your question why you don't have more degeneracies than two-fold when you don't have the potential?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs no, my question is why the degeneracies if the cyclic group of order 2 is abelian, and all its irreps are real. Raising the potential to non-unit power doesn't break this symmetry, but lifts the degeneracy, so your first comment is wrong.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now.